# Programmatically created attribute appears in database, but not in Magento back-end

Tags: php, magento, attributes

In a new Magento extension, I'm creating some custom product attributes.
But when I'm testing the extension, the attributes doesn't appears in the back-end.
When I'm looking in the database, then I see that the attributes are created...

Is it possible I'm forgetting something in my Setup.php?

That's my code: 
/Model/Resource/Eav/Setup.php

```
/**
 * @return array
 * An array with product entities: medipim_version
 */
public function getDefaultEntities()
{

    /*$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','medipim_version');*/
    //
    return array(
        'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model'                  =>  'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model'               =>  'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'                         =>  'catalog/product',
            'additional_attribute_tabel'    =>  'catalog/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection'   =>  'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'    => array(
                'medipim_version' => array(
                    'group'                             =>  'Medipim data',
                    'label'                             =>  'Version',
                    'type'                              =>  'varchar',
                    'input'                             =>  'text',
                    'default'                           =>  '',
                    //'class'                             =>  '',
                    //'backend'                           =>  '',
                    //'frontend'                          =>  '',
                    //'source'                            =>  '',
                    'global'                            =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible'                           =>  1,
                    'required'                          =>  0,
                    'user_defined'                      =>  1,
                    //'searchable'                        =>  0,
                    //'filterable'                        =>  0,
                    //'comparable'                        =>  0,
                    'visible_on_front'                  =>  1,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front'          =>  0,
                    'used_in_product_listing'           =>  1,
                    //'visible_in_advanced_search'        =>  0,
                    'unique'                            =>  0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
 }
```

sql/medipim_setup_product_entities/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->installEntities();
```

etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Crmart_Medipim>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Crmart_Medipim>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <helpers>
                <medipim>
                    <class>Crmart_Medipim_Helper</class>
                </medipim>
            </helpers>
            <models>
                <medipim>
                    <class>Crmart_Medipim_Model</class>
                </medipim>
            </models>
            <resources>
                <medipim_setup_product_entities>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Crmart_Medipim</module>
                        <class>Crmart_Medipim_Model_Resource_Eav_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                </medipim_setup_product_entities>
                <medipim_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </medipim_write>
                <medipim_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </medipim_read>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

---

**SOLUTION**

In my Setup class, I typed 'additional_attribute_tabel' instead of 'additional_attribute_table'.

Comment: Does `Crmart_Medipim_Model_Resource_Eav_Setup` extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`?

Comment: Yes. `class Crmart_Medipim_Model_Resource_Eav_Setup extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup
{`

Comment: But if I look in my database in the table `eav_attribute`, I can find the attributes. But it's not showing in my back-end. http://cl.ly/image/1x032r0t160H

Comment: Re-install it. Remove the attribute's row in `eav_attribute`, then remove the row pointing to `medipim_setup_product_entities` from `core_resource`, then install using only the installer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5191/21. I'm not familiar with your way of installing an attribute.

Comment: Ok. Solved. :)
I typed `additional_attribute_tabel` instead of `additional_attribute_table` in my setup class.

Comment: That could be avoided by just creating your attribute with `$installer->addAttribute()` where `$installer` is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` (or children of). You don't need the `installEntities/getDefaultEntities` combo. Can you add an asnwer which states what the solution was and then accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved it.

In my Setup class, I typed 'additional_attribute_tabel' instead of 'additional_attribute_table'.